# Knockout-ES5 not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I am trying to use Knockout-ES5 along side Knockout in my project. But it seems to not working at all. Here is a very simple sample taken from the official Knockout tutorials. Here is my markup code

```
    <p>First name: <input data-bind="text: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="text: lastName" /></p>
```

And here is my js file

```
    $(function () {

        var obj = {
           firstName: 'Bert',
           lastName: 'Bertington'
        }

        ko.track(obj);

        obj.firstName.subscribe(function(v){
           alert(v);
        });    
   });
```

The line **obj.firstName.subscribe(function)** crashes with the exception

"Object doesn't support property or methode 'subscribe' (IE10). I cannot seem to understand why this error. Here are the js files am using:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>    
<script src="scripts/knockout-2.debug.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/weakmap.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/knockout-es5.js"></script>
```

I have tried various combinasions: e.g

```
ko.track(obj);
ko.applyBindings(obj);
```

but still nothing. Any suggestion toward the right direction would be very much appreciated. Thank you/

Answer (score 1):

I have not used ko es5 but had a quick look at their documentation.

Looks like you need to use a method to get hold of the underlying observable:

> #### Accessing the observables
>
> If you want to access the underlying
> ko.observable for a given property, e.g., so that you can subscribe to
> receive notifications when it changes, use ko.getObservable:

```
  ko.getObservable(someModel, 'email').subscribe(function(newValue) {
  console.log('The new email address is ' + newValue); });
```

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/05/20/knockout-es5-a-plugin-to-simplify-your-syntax/

Comment: Thank a lot for the fast answer. And yes your are correct. There is not exception anymore but there is no binding either. Not only my controls remain blink (they don't receive the initial values [Bert-Bertington] but the subscribe handle is not called. It seems like ko.track does nothing...

Comment: I'd suggest making a new question with a js fiddle describing your new problem. It sounds like a different issue.

Comment: Thanks guys I solved the problem: first of all in my markup code I should have "input data-bind=value" and not "input data-bind=text" and second I must call ko.applyBindings(obj); after ko.track(obj); Now every seems to work